# encrypt and decrypt image using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, encryption, google-chrome-extension

My server using this python function to encrypt and decrypt images in a bytearray format. I want to do the same encryption in the frontend and send to this function in the backend.
how to convert this method into JavaScript

```
def encrypted_decrypted_image(image):
    key = 48
    count = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(image):
        count += 1
        image[index] = value ^ key
        if count == 10:
            break
    return image
```

Comment: What format/type is `image`? I would have thought a bytes object but you are assigning to it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's a bytearray.
I tried to find some thing equivalent to enumerate but couldn't

Comment: What type is the image in the front-end? A regular JS for loop where you increment an index would do?

Comment: It's a media Recorder data taken from the screen. I haven't draw it, I may convert it to byte array or draw it as png

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with `Array.reduce()`,

```js
// def encrypted_decrypted_image(image):
//    key = 48
//    count = 0
//    for index, value in enumerate(image):
//        count += 1
//        image[index] = value ^ key
//        if count == 10:
//            break
//    return image

function xorImage(imageBuffer, key=48){
  return imageBuffer.reduce((acc, value, index) => {
    if(index == 10) return acc;
    acc.push(value ^ key);
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(xorImage([1, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: is the input parameter imageBuffer is arraybuffer or bytearray?

Comment: because my input is a byteArray

Answer (score 1):

To get individual pixels components from an image, you would first draw that image to a canvas:

```
const image = document.getElementById('image');
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = image.width;
const height = image.height;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Draw original image: 
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Then, get the values for the pixels you are going to update:

```
const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
```

Note the shape and type of the data returned by the  [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) function:

```
ImageData ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh);
```

- `sx`: The x coordinate of the upper left corner of the rectangle from which the ImageData will be extracted.
- `sy`: The y coordinate of the upper left corner of the rectangle from which the ImageData will be extracted.
- `sw`: The width of the rectangle from which the ImageData will be extracted.
- `sh`: The height of the rectangle from which the ImageData will be extracted.

You can see it returns an `ImageData` object, [whatever that is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData). The important part here is that that object has a `.data` property which contains all our pixel values.

However, note that `.data` property is a 1-dimension [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray), which means that all the pixel's components have been flattened, so you are getting something that looks like this:

Let's say you have a 2x2 image like this:

```
 RED PIXEL |       GREEN PIXEL
BLUE PIXEL | TRANSPARENT PIXEL
```

Then, you will get them like this:

```
[ 255, 0, 0, 255,    0, 255, 0, 255,    0, 0, 255, 255,    0, 0, 0, 0          ]
|   RED PIXEL   |    GREEN PIXEL   |     BLUE PIXEL   |    TRANSPAERENT  PIXEL |
|   1ST PIXEL   |      2ND PIXEL   |      3RD PIXEL   |             4TH  PIXEL |
```

You can then transform these values however you'd like, and in your specific use case, that would be all you need to do on the frontend before sending the transformed data to the server:

```
const transformedData = encryptedDecryptedImage(data);

fetch('httsp://', { ... });
```

If you want to draw the transformed data back on the page, you first need to convert it back to [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createImageData) and [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData):

```
const imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);

imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(transformedData));

context.putImageData(transformedData, 0, 0);
```

Working example:

```js
const image = document.getElementById('image');
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = image.width;
const height = image.height;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

// Draw original image: 
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

// Transform the top half of the image (each pixel has 4 coordinates, RGB and alpha):
const maxTransformedCoords = width * Math.round(height / 2) * 4; 

// Avoid processing more than needed:
const requiredRows = Math.ceil(maxTransformedCoords / (width * 4));

// Get the pixel component values as an array:
const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, requiredRows).data;

// Your transform logic (with some changes):

const key = 48;

let count = 0;

const transformedData = data.map((value, i) => {    
  if (++count > maxTransformedCoords) return value;

  // Turn alpha coordinates opaque:
  // if ((i + 1) % 4 === 0) return 255;

  // Your logic:
  return value ** key;
});

// Turn the transformed data into an ImageData object:
const imageData = context.createImageData(width, requiredRows);
imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(transformedData));

// Draw the transformed pixels:
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

// Display it on the page:
canvas.id = 'canvas';
document.body.append(canvas);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image,
#canvas {
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background: cyan;
}

#canvas {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" >
```

⚠️ Note I'm using a small data URI to avoid `Cross-Origin` issues if I include an external image or an answer that is larger than allowed if I try to use a longer data URI.

Comment: I'm using this to record chunks from the media recorder I want know if i can use this chunks as my input for encryption : mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
    if (e.data.size > 0) {
      recordedChunks.push(e.data);
    }
  }

Comment: This example would work fine with one chunk at a time, assuming it contains a one-dimensional array where the pixel data has been already flattened. Otherwise you would have to do that first. See where I explain the return value of `getImageData()`.